# how to get duplicate data from table with sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `directors` and need to get all duplicated rows

Checking columns is `name` and `phone_number`

Table `directors`

| uuid | name | phone_number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5esd | ari | 111-222-333 |
| 6dcv | lee | 111-222-333 |
| 56js | poo | 667-784-343 |
| tug8 | ari | 866-653-343 |

I need these rows:

| uuid | name | phone_number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5esd | ari | 111-222-333 |
| 6dcv | lee | 111-222-333 |
| tug8 | ari | 866-653-343 |

ecause two upper rows has same phone number and last record has same name as first row

What I tried is

```
select d1.* from directors as d1
join (
   select d2.* from directors d2 
   group by `d2`.`uuid` 
   having count(d2.phone_number) > 1
   or count(d2.name) > 1
) d2 on d1.uuid = d2.uuid;
```

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: *get all duplicated dates* - er, what dates?

Comment: @Stu duplicates rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just one of possible options:

```
select t.* from t
join (
    select phone_number from t group by phone_number having count(phone_number) > 1
) d on t.phone_number = d.phone_number;
```

https://sqlize.online/sql/psql14/f7d63b0d5d06a4d6d428798da644dcbb/

One more example:

```
select t.* from t
join t t_copy using(phone_number)
where t.uuid != t_copy.uuid;
```

https://sqlize.online/s/MW

Comment: I want via `HAVING`

Comment: @issdilshod `I want via HAVING` and what is *having count(phone_number) > 1* ?

Comment: @ErgestBasha not working

Comment: @issdilshod please define `not working` , clearly from the example of Slava it works pretty fine and gives your expected result

Comment: updated the post can you check pls?

Comment: @issdilshod, please look https://sqlize.online/s/JW

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev and how about if I need to check from multiply tables, an example if I have `Addresses` table and also need to check by `Directors` addresses for duplicate

Comment: We can not continue here. Please ask separate question

Answer (score 2):

A couple of options you can use:

```
select * 
from t
where exists (
    select * from t t2 
    where t2.phone_number = t.phone_number and t2.uuid != t.uuid
);

select * from (
    select *, Count(*) over(partition by phone_number) cnt
    from t
)t
where cnt > 1
```